# Allocate stack upon need

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, stack-memory

I have main function that in the beginning need lots of stack, and in the end not need it. for example:

```
int main()
{
    int ans;

    {
        uint8_t buff[0x1000];
        ans = prepare(buff, sizeof(buff));
        // Now buff is not needed anymore
    }
    
    server_run(ans);

    <do more stuff without buff>

    return 0;
}
```

What I see is that the compiler allocating in the beginning of the function the space in the stack for `buff` and not free it till the end of the function. That leads that while the server runs I lack in the stack 0x1000 bytes without reason.

solutions I know I can do:

1. Allocate buff on the heap and free it before running the server.
2. Call `prepare` from different **no inline** function.

The down side in both solutions are that I need to track each local I using and the code is not clean.

Example for things I would like:

1. Some pragma before calling `server_run` that will tell the compiler to release the stack that not used anymore
2. Some compiler flag on the specific c file that will tell the compiler to allocate/free stack upon need

Comment: What method(s) are you using to determine that the compiler doesn't free the space?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I look in the assembly

Comment: If `buff` isn't used in `main` why do you define it in `main` ? Why not have it in `prepare`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Yeah, that's normal that compilers allocate all the stack space at the top of the function, except for VLAs and `alloca`.  They don't deallocate anything until the epilogue, regardless of leaving scopes within the function.  (They might overlap the storage for two objects if they can prove their lifetimes are disjoint, but they won't move the stack pointer.  In fact I'm not sure they could on Windows x64 without breaking stack  unwinding, but they can on amd64 SysV.)  Perhaps you could hack around this with a VLA leaving scope?

Comment: @arye " and not free it till the end of the function." --> does the later half of the function need this space?  Did "<do more stuff without buff>" need a large buffer also?  Was there a stack overflow because memory was not "deallocated" sooner?

Comment: It sounds like the behavior (the assembly output ignoring your local scope) might be compiler-dependent.  You might want to experiment with different compiler switches and/or different compilers, and see if you get different behavior.  You might also want to experiment with [alloca()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html).  Q: Why do you care about a measly 1K bytes, anyway?  Is this an embedded system, with severe memory constraints? Or was the 1K just a proof-of-concept example?

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't sure I understand what do you mean by 'VLA leaving scope', do you mean changing buff to be VLA?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The other half is using very little stack

Comment: @paulsm4: Indeed it is embedded system with very little RAM size (and BTW, 0x1000 bytes are 4K)

Comment: @paulsm4: I don't see how alloca() will help me here, as there is no free function to it

Comment: @arye Just wrap all code using `buff` into a function call. Then the memory is released when the function returns (at least on every system I know)

Comment: @SupportUkraine: I wrote this option in the question ('solutions I know I can do' number 2), and I wrote there why I prefer to found different solution. (BTW, it is correct just if the compiler not inlining it)

Comment: What do you mean by: "track each local" ? And for inline: If you are worried about that, gcc has a flag. Something like: `void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo()`

Comment: And re: "Allocate buff on the heap and free it before running the server." You can't be sure that `free` actually returns memory to the system.

Comment: Why not put the code defining and using `buff` into a function other than `main()` and call said function from `main()`?  When the function returns, the space allocated for `buff` will be released.

Comment: With the information that is in the question, as far as I can tell, this is an artificial problem that comes because a variable is defined in the wrong place.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As I wrote to SupportUkraine above, I already raised this option in the question...

Comment: @SupportUkraine I will try to explain: Let say I have lots of locals that take stack space before call_server called, so I need to find all of them and to move them to function (and I know it is not really problem to make it not inline). I prefer solution that I not need to search for those locals, just to catch sensitive functions such as server_run and release before them the stack somehow. And I prefer the solution to be clean of course

Comment: @arye There is not much to track. Just move everything in the local scope into a setup function. Should be simple. In any case - you should add details about this into the question so that we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Clean up the code — make it so you don't have to track each local variable.  The solutions are simple, and only require semi-decent software engineering (it is _not_ rocket science).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Indeed it is not rocket science :) but in complex system where there are multiple such places, multiple engineers that involved and very little amount of RAM, I prefer more robust solution if there is

Comment: What I propose is the robust solution — what you're seeking is a hack, and unreliable.

Comment: @arye Thanks for [The other half is using very little stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667155/allocate-stack-upon-need?noredirect=1#comment135168806_76667155).  Since the later half uses little stack, there is no advantage to free `buff[]` before the end of the function.  Sounds like the concern is not important, unless there is more we do not know about.

Comment: Do you need much stack _after `buff` "died"_ in called other functions? If so, do you experience stack overflows? If not, why bother at all?

Comment: So your real problem isn't one array, it's a bunch of small scalar variables whose address you pass to other functions and then they're unused?  So tricking the compiler with a fixed-size VLA couldn't help.  Or are they all arrays?  If their lifetimes are disjoint, a good compiler will hopefully overlap their storage.